# Unable to inherit from QAbstractItemModel

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I'm new to model/view in PyQt and I'm having trouble creating an object that inherits from the QAbstractItemModel class. Here's the class that inherits from it:

```
class MyCustomDataModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init(self, parent = None):
        super(MyCustomDataModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
```

Here's another class that tries to instantiate an object of the above type:

```
class MyCustomType(AnotherCustomTypeThatInheritsQListWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyCustomType, self).__init__(parent)

        # Instantiate a model:
        self.dataModel = MyCustomDataModel(self)
```

The above instantiation is throwing the following error at runtime:
"QAbstractItemModel(QObject parent = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'MyCustomType'" I cannot see what the problem is here, but I'm pretty new to Python / PyQt. Can someone please point out what I've done wrong? I've tried calling the instantiation line and not passing anything in but I get the same error.

Comment: After some experimenting it seems that the error crops up if the encapsulating object has a QListWidgetItem anywhere in its inheritance chain. Not sure how to proceed from here. Advice anyone?

Comment: Why the heck would you be using `QListWidgetItem` with a custom item model? More to the point, why the heck would you be creating a new item model for every single item? If you're new to pyqt, I suggest you use a [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html).

Comment: The error message tells you a bit about what is wrong. Obviously the constructor of QAbstractItemModel doesn't like what you gave it. Time to look up the documentation to see what it actually wants. Looking up the Qt class documentation is generally very helpful: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html

Comment: @ekhumoro: I started out with QListView but could not get the drag and drop to work properly. I resorted to using QListWidget and QListWidgetItem(s) with custom model because the drag and drop worked the way I needed to. I use a model for each QListWidgetItem object because these objects are associated with complex item-specific multi-field data that populates a grid of widgets.

Comment: @Trilarion: Thank you for that helpful link. I've bookmarked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more appropriate as a comment instead of an answer.

Try updating the line where you pass the MyCustomType instance to MyCustomDataModel:

```
self.dataModel = MyCustomDataModel(self)
```

Instead use:

```
self.dataModel = MyCustomDataModel()
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked...at least ,the error is gone. But I don't understand my error. What if I wish to assign a parent to MyCustomDataModel during instantiation?

Comment: The error arises when the `MyCustomType` instance is passed to `QAbstractItemModel` in `super(MyCustomDataModel, self).__init__(parent)`.  `QAbstractItemModel` is an object that will not accept the custom object you've built.  If you're going to inherit `QAbstractItemModel` then you'll need to construct `MyCustomType` as an acceptable object (i.e. inherit the class that `QAbstractItemModel` is expecting).  I suppose it might help to understand why you wanted to setup the inheritance as above with `QAbstractItemModel` and `AnotherCustomTypeThatInheritsQListWidgetItem`.

Comment: This seemed like a straight forward thing to do i.e. create a new class that inherits from QAbstractItemModel and extend it by adding a member property or two. How would one know in advance that the act of placing an object of this new class within another class that inherits from QListWidgetItem would break it?

Comment: @LKeene. Putting it inside another class is not relevant. The traceback shows you that the *parent* argument of the model must be a `QObject`. But `MyCustomType` is not a subclass of `QObject` - hence the error. There's no mystery here. If you pass a python `dict` to the `int()` function, you'll get a similar outcome (i.e. a `TypeError`).