# QDataWidgetMapper.addMapping(...) causes application to hang

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm having a really tough time trying to learn model/view in PyQt (see this thread: [Unable to inherit from QAbstractItemModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828552/unable-to-inherit-from-qabstractitemmodel)). My application is hanging when I try to add the mapping assignments. Here's my custom data model class:

```
class MyCustomDataModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init(self, parent = None):
        super(MyCustomDataModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = None


    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):

        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:

            if index.column() == 0:
                return self.parent.value0
            elif index.column() == 1:
                return self.parent.value1
            elif index.column() == 1:
                return self.parent.value2

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                self.parent.value0 = value
            elif index.column() == 1:
                self.parent.value1 = value
            elif index.column() == 2:
                self.parent.value2 = value

            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

Here's the class that's trying to use the data model. It contains variables that I'd like to map to widgets:

```
class MyCustomType(AnotherCustomTypeThatInheritsQListWidgetItem):

def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MyCustomType, self).__init__(parent)

    # Some member data:
    self.value0 = 0
    self.value1 = 1
    self.value2 = 2

    # Instantiate a model:
    self.dataModel = MyCustomDataModel()
    self.dataModel.parent = self
```

I have a composite widget that contains three QLineEdit widgets:

```
class MyCompositeWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyCompositeWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.dataMapper = QDataWidgetMapper()

        # Instantiate three line edits:
        self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit3 = QLineEdit()

        # Add widgets to layout, set layout, etc. Not shown but widgets display properly.

     def Activate(self, anInstanceofMyCustomType):

         self.dataMapper.setModel(anInstanceOfMyCustomType.dataModel)
         self.dataMapper.addMapping(self.lineEdit1, 0) # This line causes application to hang indefinately
         self.dataMapper.addMapping(self.lineEdit2, 1)
         self.dataMapper.addMapping(self.lineEdit3, 2)
```

At runtime the application hangs at the indicated "addMapping" call in the "Activate(...)" function. I find the tutorials online very unclear and have hit a road block here. I have to admit I'm pretty confused about the "index.column()" mapping but I believe this is how an index is assigned to the data members. Anyhow, any help is very much appreciated...I've spent a lot of time trying to learn this and don't have anything really to show for it so far.

Comment: One way to go here is to remove all that is not necessary, and then simplify the code even further until you arrive at a state that works. A minimal but complete example would be helping others a lot to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you have a good understanding of the classes of Qt's Model-View Programming framework. I recommend reading [its documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) (you can skip the parts about drag-drop and proxys). Read it a few times if necessary, it took me a while before I fully understood it.

Anyway, an important point is that there are a few scenarios and that you use different classes in these scenarios. In order from simple to complex they are:

1. **Use the convenience classes.** You can use this when you have a small model, and you have only a single widget with which you view
   the model. In this scenario you use the [convinience
   classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-view-convenience-classes),
   which all have names ending in 'Widget': `QListWidget`, `QTableWidget`,
   and `QTreeWidget`. They are not linked to a separate model class, you fill them directly with their corresponding item classes: `QListWidgetItem`,
   `QTableWidgetItem`, and `QTreeWidgetItem` respectively. All these classes are not meant to be subclassed! Overriding them probably leads to undefined behavior, as you are experiencing now.
2. **Use standard model classes.** You use these when you have small model but want to have multiple views on the same model. In this case you create a `QStandardItemModel` and populate it with `QStandardItem` objects. You then create one or more view classes (`QListView`, `QTableView`, or `QTreeView`) and connect them to the model.
3. **Create new models.** This is the best solution if you have a large model. You override one of the base classes, `QAbstractListModel', 'QAbstactTableModel', or 'QAbstractItemModel` (there is no `QAbstractTreeModel` unfortunately), and implement various methods. Which methods you should override depends on the fuctionality you want your model to have (see the [Model Subclassing Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference)). The benefit of this approach is a greater performance and flexibility. Your model implementation can use regular Python data structures and the `data` method will return data only for the visible cells, at request of the views. You can use regular Python data structures to store the data, there is no need to put your data in Qt item objects beforehand.

Don't mix the classes above. That is, don't put the widget items in a standard model or vice-versa.

Without knowing more about your situation, I think that scenario 2 applies to you the best. Therefore I recommend that you make a `QStandardModel` and fill it with `QStandardItem` objects. In your first iteration I would use a `QListView` or `QTableView` to inspect your model. Only when that works correctly would I connect it to a `DataWidgetMapper`. Start simple!

Finally, please make a proper [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time. Make sure it's complete! For instance, don't use constructs like `anInstanceOfMyCustomType` but show us the actual code that creates the object instance. Otherwise you risk omitting crucial information. Also it allows us to reproduce the issue ourselves, investigate if needed and check possible answers.